# How to update data for different browsers for action made in 1 application and update in application 2 in Angular project

Tags: angular, api

I'm have 2 applications(ex- application A and application B) in same project where if application A send xyz data application b need to get updated data(call api in application b if application A makes an actions). If these 2 apps opened in different browsers using Angular 12
Please help me with this scenario

Comment: we will have to use websockets to achieve this

Comment: these links might help https://javascript-conference.com/blog/real-time-in-angular-a-journey-into-websocket-and-rxjs/ , https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-websockets?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can we achieve this without web sockets or NGRX